# Evaluate fractional derivative

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, summation

I needed to evaluate the following fractional derivative of $f(t) = e^{t^2}$. The fractional derivative that I'm currently studying is the Grunwald-Letnikov fractional derivative, which is defined as follows

$$
D^{\alpha}_{t} f(t) = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} h^{-\alpha} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-\alpha)_{n}}{n!} f(t-nh),
$$

where the term $(-\alpha)_{n}$ is the Pochhammer's Symbol

$$
(-\alpha)_n = \frac{\Gamma(n - \alpha)}{\Gamma(n)}.
$$

What I would like to do is evaluate the fractional derivative of $f(t)$  in the sum above. I know that Mathematica can evaluate sums that go to infinity, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Someting to adjust in view of `Sum[Gamma[n - 1/2]/Gamma[n]/n!*Exp[(t - n*1/3)^2], {n, 0, Infinity}]` "Sum::div: Sum does not converge."

Comment: Hello, @user64494 thanks for your comment! Would the limit term in the fractional derivative definition affect the end result?

Comment: If a series diverges for values  $h>0, h \le 1/3$, its limit at $h=0$ does not exist. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: Good. I'm not familiarized with those summation concepts. Thanks for your answer! I would like to ask if there is a good book about this? Thanks again!

Comment: @user4642 To calculate the Grunwald-Letnikov fractional derivative we can use Theorem and eq. (4) from http://www.diogenes.bg/fcaa/volume7/fcaa74/74_Ortigueira_Coito.pdf

Comment: Thank you @Alex Trounev for the Ref! I'll take a look at it.